# Repeated error for every activation_9n (eg: activation_9, ..activation_45.. etc)

Tags: keras, classification, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition

"ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_81 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (7,)"

I am performing a multiclass classification of 7 classes for speech emotion classification using a neural network, but it fails at this point

```
cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, 
                     y_train, 
                     batch_size=16, 
                     epochs=700,
                     validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test), 
                     callbacks=[mcp_save, lr_reduce])
```

at the line **callbacks=[mcp_save, lr_reduce]**

mcp_save being

```
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('model/aug_noiseNshift_2class2_np.h5', 
                            save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
```

and lr_reduce being

```
lr_reduce = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.9, patience=20, min_lr=0.000001)
```

Final layer of NN
Dense(7) for 7 classes

```
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
```

compiled model using

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy', fscore])
```

I have already transformed the dataset, with normalised values, changed the loss function to 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' from 'categorical_crossentropy'. Nothing has worked just pushed the error from activation_9 to activation_18 to activation_45 to activation_54 to now activation_81. But the error is still there.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
I am new to neural networks.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you have labels as numbers, that means `y_train` has shape `(samples, 1)` and you should use `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`.

If you have labels as one-hot encodings, that means `y_train` has shape `(samples, 7)` and you should use `'categorical_crossentropy'`.